# java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk6.WrappedConnectionJDK6 cannot be cast

Tags: java, jboss, oracle11g, spatial, java-6

Application Version: **JBoss 7.0.0, Oracle 11g (ojdbc6.jar) and JDK 6 version**

I have a problem when I am trying to insert the value for CLOB Data type using `CLOB.createTemporary` function, getting the below exception.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk6.WrappedConnectionJDK6 cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection
```

After searching in multiple forums, did not find any solution. 
https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=279238

Basic steps required to deploy a WAR file and configuring the JBoss oracle driver pool configuration is done. But, still not able to get through this issue.

Please provide solution to fix this problem.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/277665/1285418) might help you.

Comment: Could you replace ojdbc6.jar with ojdbc14.jar and check the driver class name oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

Comment: Phani, I'm using Java 6 version and the corresponding driver for connecting to oracle should be ojdbc6.jar. May know how are you relating this with ojdbc14.jar file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have solved my problem with the below approach.

**Summary:** Class loader should not load the Oracle driver from server lib/modules and in web archive (WAR file). Keep the oracle driver only in server lib (JBoss 7 ver).

**JBoss 7:**

- Created a new JBoss deployment descriptor file(jboss-deployment-structure.xml)

  1. Updated the (ironjacamar-jdbc-1.0.3.Final.jar) iron module in the jboss deployment structure file
  2. Created the ojdbc6.jar as module in the JBoss 7 structure
     Updated the objbc module in the jboss deployment structure file
  3. Example:

     ```
     <jboss-deployment-structure> 
         <deployment>
             <dependencies>
                 <module name="org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters" slot="main"/>
                 <module name="com.oracle.ojdbc6" slot="main"/>
             </dependencies>
         </deployment> 
     </jboss-deployment-structure>
     ```

**Web module:**
- Removed the ojdbc6.jar file from the web archive(WAR file)

If you find any issue in solving, please let me know.

Comment: Solution is great but take attention, the module names are configured in JBoss self.  I had to change `com.oracle.ojdbc6` to `com.oracle`.

Comment: Hi @Rajkumar, I'm facing the issue and situation seems similar. can you please assist?
https://stackoverflow.com/q/60658912/2174455

Answer (score 1):

What's happening here is that JBoss wraps the oracle connection (oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection) with it's own one (org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk6.WrappedConnectionJDK6). You have to call #getUnderlyingConnection() to get the underlying connection.

```
WrappedConnection wrapped = (WrappedConnection) conn;
CLOB clob = CLOB.createTemporary(wrapped.getUnderlyingConnection(), true, CLOB.DURATION_SESSION);
```

However I ask myself whether the following wouldn't work as well in your case.

```
ps.setClob(4, new StringReader(data));
```

Comment: Hi Philippe, I can understand your answer. The problem now I'm facing is, I'm not able to type cast the "conn" object to WrappedConnection object. While I try to typecast, I'm get this exception "java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk6.WrappedConnectionJDK6 cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection"

Comment: So `WrappedConnection#getUnderlyingConnection()` again returns a `WrappedConnectionJDK6`?

Have you tried to delete the whole `CLOB.createTemporary` code (and the cast to `WrappedConnection`) and just go with `ps.setClob(4, new StringReader(data));`

Answer (score 0):

Got a similar problem in a Rails App with Jruby 1.7.2, JBoss 7.1 and Oracle (oracle_enhanced adapter)

```
Java::JavaLang::ClassCastException: oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection
```

This solution worked for me.

I put the jboss-deployment-structure.xml in the config/ directory of the rails app and updated the warbler config to include the file in the war file:

```
config.webinf_files += FileList["config/jboss-deployment-structure.xml"]
```

After deploy all worked fine ... Thx a lot.