# java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk6.WrappedConnectionJDK6

Tags: jdbc, jboss, connection, classcastexception, jboss6.x

I have the following problem:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk6.WrappedConnectionJDK6 cannot be cast
```

I did try to add the `ironjacamar-jdbc-1.0.17.Final-redhat-1.jar` in the project-tree under lib.

When I deploy the project I get the following exception:

```
org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk6.WrappedConnectionJDK6 cannot be to org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk6.WrappedConnectionJDK6
```

The code where the exception occurs:

```
java.sql.Connection connection =  ds.getConnection();
WrappedConnection c =  ((WrappedConnection)connection).getUnderlyingConnection();
OracleConnection conn = (OracleConnection) c;
```

I did add a new file, *jboss-deployment-structure.xml*, with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure> 
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters" slot="main"/>
            <module name="com.oracle.ojdbc6" slot="main"/>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment> 
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

In this case i get:

```
moduleloading error can not load 

<module name="com.oracle.ojdbc6" slot="main"/
```

Manifest.MF:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: 
Dependencies:  org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters
```

Removing

```
<module name="com.oracle.ojdbc6" slot="main"/>
```

I get

```
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection
```

It want cast everything to everything JBoss kidding me ?

Can you tell me what I have to do in order to get an OracleDamnedConnection ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247702/java-lang-classcastexception-org-jboss-jca-adapters-jdbc-jdk6-wrappedconnection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the file jboss-deployement-structure.xml

you i had to write:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <jboss-deployment-structure> 
 <deployment>
 <dependencies>
 <module name="org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters" slot="main"/>
 <module name="com.oracle" />

 </dependencies>

 </deployment> 
 </jboss-deployment-structure>
```

because it has to match the path of the jar ojdbc, last folder was Main.
and it looks inside Main.  so i had the path /com/oracle/main/ojdbc.jar

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by editing the jboss-deployment-structure.xml file:

```
<dependencies>
     <module name="org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters" slot="main"/>
     <module name="com.oracle.ojdbc6" slot="main"/> 
</dependencies>
```

Comment: How does this differ from the configuration the OP originally reported as not working? It’s possible that this works now, on a newer version, over six years later. But it’s not really a solution to the original problem if it uses the exact same configuration that the OP was reporting an error with. Am I missing something?