# How to pass java list of objects to oracle stored procedure (Cannot use Spring)

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I have a list of POJO's that I want to pass to an Oracle Stored Procedure and then loop through that list in the stored proc and run update statements

I've tried using a StructDescriptor but I keep getting an exception due to my connection object

```
(java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk6.WrappedConnectionJDK6 cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection)

public void MyMethod(List<myObject> myObjectList) {

private Connection con = null;
private CallableStatement stmt = null;

try {

    con = getConnection();  

    String query = "{call "+getStoredProcedureName()+"(?)}";
    stmt.setArray(1, myObjectList);
    stmt = con.prepareCall(query);

     stmt.execute();

} catch(Exception e) {

     throw e;
}
}
```

In Oracle

```
create or replace TYPE "MY_REC" AS OBJECT
(
   field_one varchar2(50),
   field_two varchar2(100)
);

create or replace TYPE "MY_REC_T" AS TABLE OF MY_REC;
```

I expect myObjectList to be passed to my stored procedure

Comment: Can you show us what `getConnection` does? I can find no answers which address passing an array of Java objects to an Oracle stored procedure across a JBoss connection. It appears that you're going to have to use something compatible with `oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/10247702/1509264

Answer (score 0):

Working with other connection wrappers (not jboss), I have had to unwrap the connection to get the underlying `OracleConnection`:

```java
Connection connection = getConnection();
if ( !connection.isWrapperFor( OracleConnection.class ) )
{
  // throw exception
}
OracleConnection oConnection = (OracleConnection) connection.unwrap( OracleConnection.class );
```

The [JBoss documentation](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/SetUpAOracleDatasource) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10275093/1509264) also suggests that you could use:

```java
WrappedConnection wrapped = (WrappedConnection) getConnection();
OracleConnection oConnection = (OracleConnection) wrapped.getUnderlyingConnection();
```

After that, there are multiple other answers on how to pass a Java array to Oracle SQL [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47711778/1509264) [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51144013/1509264) [[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34699771/1509264)